# Scraping itemprop="name" in BeatifulSoup in Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
names = soup.find_all('meta', itemprop='name')
prices = soup.find_all('span', class_='price product-price')

for price, name in zip(prices, names):
    modelName = name
    modelPrice = price.text
    csv_writer.writerow([modelName, modelPrice])
print('Parsing prices: DONE')
csv_file.close()
```

After this code, i'm exporting it to csv file and get something like this:

```
    "
"<meta content=""TEXT HERE"" itemprop=""name"">
</meta>","
          PRICE HERE
```

I want to get rid of exported code, i need just a name and price. Code of website looks this:

```
<a itemprop="name" class="product-name listgrid" href="https://websitename.com" title="Name of needed model to parse</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want the text part of a document or tag, you can use the `get_text()` method. It returns all the text in a document or beneath a tag, as a single Unicode string.

In your case smth similar should work:

```
soup.find_all()[0].get_text()
```

I think there is no need to make a loop.